# Automating select, copy, find, copy paste in order

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are two excel sheets I'm working on. The first is made up of 300 names of programs, one each row, and with 2 additional columns with version numbers and extra info. The second is a lot alike, but has about 100 rows and has 2  columns with  different information from the first.

example:

Adobe premiere , 6.0.2, video-editing software

Around 50 of these programs match by name (they are both in sheet 1 and 2), and i would like to import extra information about all matching programs from sheet 2 into sheet one, next to the existing information. That would mean that 50 or so rows have 2 additional columns and that about half of sheet 2 is left unmatched.

By hand, this means copying the names from sheet 2, finding a match in sheet one, then copying the 2 columns from sheet 2 and pasting them in the corresponding location in sheet 1. I hope there might be a better way to do this. Does anyone know a way?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you require by using a combination of `VLOOKUP` and `IFERROR`:
Enter the following formula in your first worksheet and replace the name of the second workbook and worksheet:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'[Workbook2Name.xlsx]Sheetname'!$A:$C,2,0),"")
```

This should return you the second column of the matching entry (assuming that the data is stored in columns A-C).

Answer (score 0):

Though I may be misinterpreting your question, I read it to mean that you want to return data from two columns in Sheet2. If that's the case, @Peter's formula won't quite work. That is because VLOOKUP will return data from one column only.

The following formula would do the job. For illustrative purposes, I assume the program names in Sheet1 begin in cell A2 and your data in Sheet2 are in cells G2:I11.

```
  =IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet2!$G$2,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$G$2:$G$11,0)-1,1,1,2),"-")
```

This is an array formula. To enter it, you would highlight cells B2:B3 in Sheet1, input the formula, making sure to complete the entry with the CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER key combination. Then you would copy it down to the end of the data in Sheet1.

It works by using MATCH to find the row in which the program name in Sheet1 matches the program in Sheet2 (relative to the first data cell in Sheet2). It then uses OFFSET to return the corresponding two cells of data from Sheet2.

As @Peter notes, if second sheet is in another workbook, you would need to preface the references to that sheet with the workbook name, and if the sheet has a name other than the default, you would need to use the sheet name in the formula as well, resulting in:

```
  =IFERROR(OFFSET('[Workbook2Name.xlsx]Sheet2name'!$G$2,MATCH(A2,'[Workbook2Name.xlsx]Sheet2name'!$G$2:$G$11,0)-1,1,1,2),"-").
```

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP()` can return more than one column.

One uses what Excel calls an `array constant`. They take the form of `{2,3}` to use as an example the one you'd need for this.

You do need to make out references to the other sheet with its name, but that's been covered by both other answers. A simple version, as if both sets of information were on the same page (perhaps in A1:A300 and N1:P100, and looking to augment the latter), would look like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N1,$A1:$A100,{2,3},FALSE),"")
```

You use `{2,3}` because you want columns 2 and 3 of the lookup range.

One would copy it into Q1:Q100 and the N1 reference would change to match the row. One would have Q1:Q100 highlighted at that moment, but column R would also be filled. If one were OK with the formula results being permanent, one could stop at this point. If one wished it to be converted to data, no formulas, one could extend the highlight both columns, copy, then paste special pasting values only. If one further wanted the empty-looking cells to be really empty, one could keep them highlighted and press `Ctrl-G` for GoTo and choose a "special" GoTo, that of selecting empty cells. Once done, one could press Delete and they'd all be truly empty again.

(Naturally, one could bring the data the other way by reversing the choice of references.)

But `VLOOKUP()` can absolutely return more than one column's value!